# Why was I told to include a programming language tag for an [nginx] question?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

- It already had the tag nginx which is the configuration language at hand.
- The person that answered the question did a fine job and obviously knew what the question was about.

[image]

[Unduplicating prox_pass in nginx location blocks](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14066/unduplicating-prox-pass-in-nginx-location-blocks)

It's just annoying if you don't even do cursory googling to figure out if it's correct to lock it in the first place when it's that old and already answered with a correct tag.

And by cursory googling I mean this was literally the [second result on Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936260/what-language-are-nginx-conf-files) for "nginx language".

Comment: I did some searching myself, and perhaps I somehow missed that.  If so, I apologize and I'll reverse these actions.

Comment: @Jamal Retroactively locking questions from 2012 that has already been answered acceptably is still crazy even just because they are missing a tag. I have enough code to maintain already, why am I suddenly beholden to maintaining 4 year old stack overflow questions?

Comment: Please keep in mind that a closure is not the same as a lock.  Old questions can still be dealt with for maintenance reasons, but in this case I was incorrect and I appreciate you bringing this to my attention.

Comment: @Jamal Old questions should be dealt with by the moderator or the existing review tooling if the rules change where the Q&A is still considered to meet the quality standards. It's not cool to ask the user base to maintain things they posted years ago.